# Windows 10 - Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard keeps starting while typing

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse

I'll be typing away and the Microsoft Keyboard and Mouse application will suddenly start and interrupt whatever I was doing. I cannot seem to replicate the issue, it just happens randomly when I'm typing quickly.

How do I determine which keyboard shortcut is starting this application, so that I can disable it?

Comment: What application starts? Could be a scheduled task also that is starting the application every x minutes.

Comment: "the Microsoft Keyboard and Mouse application will suddenly start" - Huge ass dialog without a frame that just pops up over whatever I'm doing at the moment.